# Visual Studio Duplicate Shortcut Not Working

Tags: visual-studio

I have always used `Ctrl` + `D` to duplicate lines in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.8.5.

But recently, for seemingly no reason, it doesn't work. It doesn't even respond. It doesn't work when text is selected or not.

I was wondering if anyone else was encountering this issue. I wonder if it has something to do with an update or something. Any information or help to fix this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed new extension like Resharper?

Comment: Ctrl+D sounds like a ReSharper binding, not a VS default one. You can bind it yourself to VS's built-in duplication comment, as in Sergey's answer.

Comment: I did install Resharper, but then I deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS keyboard options, check what is assigned to the Ctrl+D shortcut and Edit.Duplicate command:

[image]

Comment: That worked. This was really bugging me because I use duplicate a lot. Thanks a lot!